# How to estimate Parameters of Black-schole or GBM in R

Tags: r

How can I estimate the Drift and Volatility of GBM or BROWNIAN MOTION PROCESS in R code ?. there are some code in python But there in not anything in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found my answer :

```
# calculating log returns
returns <- diff(log(price))
# calculate mu (drift)
mu = mean(returns)
# calculate sigma
sigma = sd(returns)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `Sim.DiffProc` package, an example:

```
library(Sim.DiffProc)

# simulate a trajectory of a GBM
# (theta: drift factor, sigma: volatility)
set.seed(666)
traj <- GBM(N=10000, t0=0, T=1, x0=1, theta=4, sigma=2)

# fit the parameters
fx <- expression( theta[1]*x ) ## drift coefficient of model (theta1 = theta)
gx <- expression( theta[2]*x ) ## diffusion coefficient of model (theta2 = sigma)
fit <- fitsde(data = traj, drift = fx, diffusion = gx, 
              start = list(theta1=3, theta2=3), 
              lower = c(0, 0), control = list(maxit=1000))
coef(fit) ## estimates
#   theta1   theta2 
# 7.042467 2.000404 
confint(fit) ## confidence intervals
#           2.5 %    97.5 %
# theta1 3.121749 10.963185
# theta2 1.972680  2.028127
```